# How do I write a Chrome extension to block all Quora answers that meet some criteria (e.g. with 0 votes)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to write a Chrome extension which can block all answers with 0 votes, like AdBlock, because sometimes there would be too many answers to read under a hot topic.

Does anyone know what techniques I should learn to start working on it? Currently I read the get started turotial: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted. And what other techniques should I learn next? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @r5d Because there are too many posts under some questions, I want to block answers that satisfy some criteria.

Comment: This is _not_ a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create files exactly like how its instructed in the tutorial you provided(you can rename filenames if you like) in the original post. And in the popup.js insert following line of code:

```
jQuery('.no_count').closest('.pagedlist_item').hide();
```

It will then hide all the answer with zero votes. However, you may need to refresh the page for the answers to show up again if they receives any vote after you land on the page.

Comment: Could I extend this to more general cases? What techniques should I learn to implement blocking functionalities like this?

Comment: Ofcourse, you can do a lot more with it. I would suggest as Zig Mandel did, learn about Javascript/CSS/HTML and see where your imaginations will take you. By the way, if my solution worked for you, you probably want to accept this as your answer.  Thanks.